# Sorting folders by name, but files by modification time

Tags: file-browser

In Blenders file browser, I can sort all items by name or modification time. But what I am used to in other file managers like Krusader or Total Commander, is files ordered by modification time, so that the last used file is always on top, but folders always ordered by name.

I'm sure there is no native way in Blenders settings to change this behaviour, but is there any addon or other solution to make this possible?

Comment: I guess Blender simply uses the operating system's sorting method. At least on my Windows 10 computer the Explorer sorts those things the same, if I sort by modification date files and folders are both sorted by modification date nad nothing by name. Only difference between the Explorer and Blender's file browser is, Blender puts folders on top, the Explorer at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very specific functionality you describe. Unfortunately, there is currently no way to achieve this with native Blender's File Browser even with Python. There can be no add-on for this in Blender's file browser, because there [doesn't seem to be any functionality for that exposed in Blender's Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FileSelectParams.html#bpy.types.FileSelectParams.sort_method). If there was some add-on capable of this, it would have to open some file browser that is not made using Blender's Python API. It might be possible to use Python to add a list of folders in current path on the side like these lists:

[image]

Those could be sorted any way one can imagine.

Comment: +1  A good answer isn't always a solution. :)

Comment: It is still possible to further pursue the side panel list option. But I suspect that might not be a very good workaround.